# Identifying an Android application even between builds

Tags: android, apk, android-package-managers, android-install-apk

My question is, what accessible values of an application do change when installing debug builds after each other. I can't write into the code and the apk's, I just want to know (through ApplicationInfo, PackageInfo, or anything other), which apk is currently installed.

So the versionCode and versionName properties don't change, but is there something I can query from the package manager, and changes every time?

Comment: An apk is a zip file, and may well have timestamps on its contents.

Comment: Indeed, but I can't make a connection between those and the installed versions.

Comment: Why not? The apk file is in the device, you'd have to look into the most official way of finding it but there are many ways.

Comment: The apk's of installed applications are only accessible with root access - which I don't have.
Anyways, I don't know anything from the timestamp. The user might install them in a different order, which means the created timestamp may vary.

Comment: No.  Root is not required.  And I don't mean the timestamp of the apk, but the timestamps of its still-packed contents.  However, if you are now talking about others' apps, note that google play requires a unique version number for each upload it accepts.

Comment: It's for an apk management app, where users can install debug apks. The problem is detecting the currently installed version of the app (match to apk).